# Prove $\int_\alpha ^\beta (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)dx = -\frac{1}{6}(\beta -\alpha )^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

In addition, does anyone know what that equation is called?

I know that it’s a property of definite integral

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Why not just expand the product, integrate termwise, and simplify?

Comment: Also, it is a consequence of the formula for the area of a (symmetric) parabolic segment.

Answer (score 1):

You can employ symmetry to solve the problem. Let $\gamma = \frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}$ and $s = x - \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$ then

\begin{align} 
\int_\alpha^\beta (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)\ dx &= \int_{-\gamma}^\gamma (s+\gamma)(s-\gamma)\ ds \\
&= \int_{-\gamma}^{\gamma} (s^2 - \gamma^2) ds \\
&= -\frac{4\gamma^3}{3} \\
& = -\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^3}{6} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As  $\alpha\le x\le\beta$

$-(\beta-\alpha)\le2x-(\alpha+\beta)\le\beta-\alpha$

WLOG $2x-(\alpha+\beta)=(\beta-\alpha)\cos2t\iff x=\alpha\sin^2t+\beta\cos^2t$

to reach at [Beta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\xi = (x-\alpha)/(\beta-\alpha)$.

Observe that
\begin{equation}
\int_\alpha ^\beta (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)dx = (\beta-\alpha)^3\int_0^1\xi(\xi-1) d\xi = -\frac{1}{6}(\beta-\alpha)^3
\end{equation}

Comment: This formulation has the downside, that the trivial case $\beta=\alpha$ needs to be discussed to show that the formula is still valid.

Comment: Let me add, If $\alpha=\beta$, integral is $0$. I am not even sure Riemann Integral make sense since no partition can be defined for a point, or it is obviously $0$ for Lebesgue Integral. RHS is $0$ too.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can also integrate by parts:

$$\int_\alpha^\beta (x-\alpha)(x-\beta) \; dx = \left.\frac{(x-\alpha)^2(x-\beta)}{2} \right|_\alpha^\beta - \int_\alpha^\beta \frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{2}\; dx $$

$$= 0  -\left.\frac{(x-\alpha)^3}{6}\right|_\alpha^\beta =-\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^3}{6}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Denote: $x-\alpha=t \Rightarrow x-\beta=t+\alpha-\beta \Rightarrow dx=dt$. Then:
$$\begin{align}\int_\alpha^\beta (x-\alpha)(x-\beta) \; dx &=\int_0^{\beta-\alpha} t(t+\alpha-\beta) \; dx =\\
&=\int_0^{\beta-\alpha} t^2+t(\alpha-\beta) \; dx =\\
&=\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{t^2}{2}(\alpha-\beta)\right)\big{|}_0^{\beta-\alpha}=\\
&=\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^3}{3}-\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^3}{2}=\\
&=-\frac{(\beta-\alpha)^3}{6}.\end{align}$$